# Dependency collision between play-services-map and firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services

Im trying to add firebase to a project that i already started, But in the build.gradle (app) i am having a dependency collision between play-services-maps and firebase, i looked everywhere and tried changing the version number but still not working. 
here is the build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.tencho.test"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

//    //Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
//    //FirebaseUI Auth
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Build.gradle (project level)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

//        The google-services plugin has 2 main functions:
//        1) Process the google-services.json file and produce Android resources that can be used in your
//        application's code
//        2) Add dependencies for basic libraries required for the services you have enabled. This step requires
//        that the apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' line be at the bottom of your app/build.gradle file
//        so that no dependency collisions are introduced.
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You should use the same version for firebase and google play services.

Comment: All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 16.0.1, 16.0.0, 15.0.4, 15.0.1, 12.0.1. Examples include com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1 and com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You are using inconsistent version.

Let me tell you simple example.

If you are using google play services 11.8.0, then firebase should also be in same version..

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

So the main thing to be noted is, you are using inconsistent versions.

Comment: Can you clear up two things for me, im sort of new to android. 1) what if there is no play-services-maps:16.0.1 to match with firebase? I have to user a older version? 2) if i do use what you posted i then get a error in the support.appcompat

Comment: It's throwing error because you might have not updated the build in sdk manager. Let me know what error it's displaying in appcompat?

Comment: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.1.0, 25.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0

Comment: I got it to work by explicitly stating the version of the mediarouter. But my question still is what if i want to use the latest version of firebase 16.0.1 and the play-services doesnt have 16.0.1

Comment: You need to update the play services build in sdk. click SDK Manager and update it. Then it will work.

Comment: But now I still get this error All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 25.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0...Even though i have explicitly stated in my gradle implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'

Comment: It is not true. Now you can use different version of firebase and google play services libraries. Also the play services libraries are not in sdk, but in the google maven repo.